# undefined labels in chart.js

Tags: jquery, datatables, chart.js

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    fetch_data();

    var hour_chart;

    function fetch_data(start_date = '', end_date = '')
    {
        var dataTable = $('#order_table').DataTable({
            "processing" : true,
            "serverSide" : true,
            'columns': [
                                { data: 'project_name' , "width" : "20%"},
                                { data: 'total' , "width" : "20%"},

                            ],

            "ajax" : {
                type:"POST",
                data:{start_date:start_date, end_date:end_date} ,         

            },
            
            "drawCallback" : function(settings)
            {
                var hours_date = [];
                var hour = [];

                for(var count = 0; count < settings.aoData.length; count++)
                {
                    hours_date.push(settings.aoData[count]._aData[0]);
                    hour.push(parseFloat(settings.aoData[count]._aData[1]));
                }

                
            

                var chart_data = {
                    labels:hours_date,
                    datasets:[
                        {
                            label : 'Hours',
                            backgroundColor : 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
                            color : '#fff',
                            data:hour
                        }
                    ]   
                };

                var group_chart3 = $('#bar_chart');

                if(hour_chart)
                {
                    hour_chart.destroy();
                }

                hour_chart = new Chart(group_chart3, {
                    type:'bar',
                    data:chart_data
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm trying to take the data in the table and create a graph with jquery, but I couldn't do it.

[image]

I don't know what aoData and _aData do. Count counts correctly and 4 labels are produced, but the names are not written properly and the corresponding hours data does not work on the graph in the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix is to change these lines of code from this:

```js
hours_date.push(settings.aoData[count]._aData[0]);
hour.push(parseFloat(settings.aoData[count]._aData[1]));
```

...to this:

```js
hours_date.push(settings.aoData[count]._aData.project_name);
hour.push(parseFloat(settings.aoData[count]._aData.total));
```

Then you will (or should) get this:

[image]

---

**Explanation**

Your JSON data source has row data as an array of objects - for example:

```js
[ { "project_name": "AUDI", "total": 118 },
{ "project_name": "BMW", "total": 60 },
{ "project_name": "FALLON", "total": 40 },
{ "project_name": "TOG", "total": 217 } ]
```

That is why you need to refer to that data using the item names such as `_aData.project_name`.

The example (you maybe copied from somewhere) was almost certainly using an array of arrays:

```js
[ ["AUDI", 118 ],
[ "BMW", 60 ],
[ "FALLON", 40 ],
[ "TOG", 217 ] ]
```

So that is why the code in your question uses array indexes `[0]` and `[1]`.

---

**Final Thought**

It's probably better to avoid using the `settings` values `aoData` and `_aData` as these are internal variable names - and they are a bit cryptic. As a refactoring exercise, you could change this to use the DataTables API - for example [`rows().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()).

That is a bit more work, but results in clearer code, at the end.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your suggestion. Also thank you for your help :)